# SQL Server database design users, groups, roles, memebers

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have the following SQL Server db with one table so far.

```
----------------
|Users         | 
----------------
| UserId    PK |
|              |
| Other fields |
----------------
```

I need to add few more tables to it which is not a problem but this is the goal:

```
----------------    ----------------    ----------------   ---------------- 
|Users         |    |Roles         |    | Teams       |    | Groups       | 
----------------    ----------------    ----------------   ---------------- 
| UserId    PK |    | RoleId    PK |    | TeamId    PK |   | GroupId   PK | 
|              |    |              |    |              |   |              | 
| Other fields |    | Other fields |    | Other fields |   | Other fields | 
----------------    ----------------    ----------------   ----------------
```

What I need to achieve is the following:

- I have X amount of users

  - User1
  - User2
  - UserX
- I have 3 roles only for all users to use in all teams and groups

  - Admin
  - Member
  - Visitor
- One user can create X amount of teams

  - Team1
  - Team2
  - TeamX
- One user can create X amount of groups

  - Group1
  - Group2
  - GroupX
- Groups and Teams can have users assigned to them with different roles (Admin, Member, Visitor)
- One user can belong to one or many team or groups
- One user can belong to one or many roles

I have some hard time understanding the relation between those tables.

Here is what I managed to achieve based on the answer from @Robertas Valeika.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 3 more tables.
UsersRoles
UsersRolesGroups
UsersRolesTeams.

Relationships:

UsersRoles - UsersRolesGroups,
Groups - UsersRolesGroups

UsersRoles - UsersRolesTeams,
Teams - UsersRolesTeams

Users - UsersRoles,
Roles - UsersRoles.

And add FK to users in groups and teams tables to identify creator of group and team.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I managed to do it. http://i57.tinypic.com/2r2c51i.png Can you check if everything is ok, relationship (1..*, *..* ...etc)

Comment: Every table must have one column as a PK (make extra one if needed). And relationships Teams - UserRolesTeams (one to many) same with groups and UserRoles - UserRolesTeams (one to many). And i don't see creator column on Teams and Groups.

Comment: This is final version. By the way if there will be only 3 roles then you don't need Roles table. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_5E4_MNQcdQ0hydXVEdU5ZZXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The url you sent doesn't work. Yes there will be only 3 roles.

Comment: My bad is working just never used so I had to login to google.

Comment: So basically if I remove the Role table then I can just add another column within the UsersRoles table called `Role` which will contain the actual Role name?

Comment: Yes if it is this specific situation and in future you wont need extra information within roles. But if you want to keep normal form of database you must have Roles (btw use singular not plural form Role) table.

Comment: Then I guess I will just let it like that without removing the Role table. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62311/discussion-between-david-dury-and-robertas-valeika).