# How to use JPA to generate jointable where an entity joins with a join table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to implement the JPA Entity POJOs for a User-Role-Team-Group model from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145734/sql-server-database-design-users-groups-roles-memebers)

Here is an ERD for the schema:

[ER Diagram](http://oi66.tinypic.com/116tj6w.jpg)

I am not able to figure out the entity model in JPA.

Here is some code that I am working on

Account Entity

```
@Entity
public class Account extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long accountId;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean accountNonExpired;
private boolean accountNonLocked;
private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNT_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
private Set<Role> userRoles;
```

Role Entity

```
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long roleId;
private String roleName;
```

The BaseEntity is just common fields with a @PrePersist and @PreUpdate

How do I add Teams to the mix here using the jointable between Account and Roles for instance?

**Update :**

I was able to get the desired table structure using the below code:

*Accounts:*

```
@Entity
public class Accounts extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean accountNonExpired;
private boolean accountNonLocked;
private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
private boolean enabled;
private boolean ldapManaged;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<AccountsRoles> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Groups:*

```
@Entity
public class Groups extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNTS_ROLES_GROUPS")
private List<AccountsGroups> accounts;
```

*Roles:*

```
@Entity
public class Roles extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String roleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<AccountsRoles> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Teams:*

```
@Entity
public class Teams extends BaseEntity{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private String managerEmail;
private String teamLeadEmail;
private String distributionListEmail;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNTS_ROLES_TEAMS")
List<AccountsRoles> accounts;
```

*AccountsGroups:*

```
@Entity
public class AccountsGroups implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@ManyToOne
private Accounts account;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Groups group;

}
```

*AccountsRoles:*

```
@Entity
public class AccountsRoles implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Accounts account;

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Roles role;
```

But, I'm not sure how do I navigate the chain.

For instance how do I get Account -> Role -> Team -> Group

Comment: You dont refer to some join table in some other relation, since the join table simply represents the first relation. If you want to make use of the data there you invent some other entity representing the join table.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<AccountRole> userRoles;
}

@Entity
public class AccountRole {
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //don't delete with cascade
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
private Account account;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //don't delete with cascade
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
private Role role;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterŠály, I will try this approach. So I assume, to then add Teams to this, I have to join Team with the new AccountRole entity?

Comment: @NeilDCruz entities Team and Role will have property AccountRole. Create entities and check if generated model fits your ERD.